# UIAlertView showing two buttons that are the same color

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I'm trying to make a UIAlertView which has the same two colors for two buttons. I don't want it to have a cancel button:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Place Call" 
                                                    message:@"Would you like to call this contact's Home or Cell phone?" 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Cell",@"Home",nil];
```

But that doesn't do the trick. The "Cell" button is like a blueish color and the "Home" button is like a grayish color.

Comment: The reason is because the Home button is the default button.  I don't k now of a way to change that, the _defaultButton ivar is private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `objectAtIndex:` to find the buttons (might take some guessing/experimenting) and change their colors via `CGRect` or custom views. I don't know exactly how that would work but I think that's worth a try. Maybe with `layer`? Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do your custom AlertView if you would like. Create a view and put how many buttons you want and adjust the colors.
Then show this view when you want to alert your user.

Comment: Check here to create a view: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html  then create your own UIButton in custom type here it is : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html  then put your button on View.